# calculate the difference the dates

Tags: apex, community

iam trying to calculate the difference between date but there is error

ERRORS:-

```
Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void YEAR(Date).

Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void TODAY()
```

pleae help me.

```
public void update(){

       integer b=YEAR(PA.Date__c)-YEAR(TODAY());
      system.debug(b);
    

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
.year()
```

This is working for me :

```
Case c = [SELECT  id , CreatedDate FROM Case LIMIT 1];
integer b = c.CreatedDate.year() -System.TODAY().year();
System.debug(b);
```

Reference:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_date.htm#apex_System_Date_year

Answer (score 4):

In Apex, you can use the [Date](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_date.htm) functions.

To calculate the difference of 2 dates you can use `daysBetween()` and `monthsBetween`.

```
Date earliestDate = Date.today().addDays(-7);
Date latestDate = Date.today();

Integer daysBetween = earliestDate.daysBetween(latestDate);
Integer monthsBetween = earliestDate.monthsBetween(latestDate);
```

Note, `monthsBetween` in this example will return a value of 1 as y days prior to today was in the month of April and we are now in May.

You cannot use TODAY() here, instead make use of the `today()` function in the Date class. The closest you will get to using such a format is TODAY in a [SOQL literal](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm).

Answer (score 1):

```
Date startDate = Date.today();
Date endDate = Date.today().addDays( 90 );
Integer noOfDays = startDate.daysBetween( endDate );
system.debug( 'Output is ' + noOfDays );
```